# Carriage return in a default value of a xp:inputTextarea

Tags: xpages

This seems like it should be easy, but Its not really working for me.  I'm trying to add a carriage return into the default value of a inputTextarea \r and \n don't seem to work, anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use @NewLine() as the separator

Default value "Marky"+@NewLine()+"Billy"